# Why ssh seems to hang

Tags: ssh

I don't seem to get  past this and it seems to hang

```
[root@server12 ~]#  ssh -1  munish@174.25.47.229
ssh: connect to host 174.25.47.229 port 22: Connection timed out
```

or

```
[root@server12 ~]#  ssh 174.25.47.229
ssh: connect to host 174.25.47.229 port 22: Connection timed out
```

I have added the public key to `/root/.ssh/known_hosts`.
am i missing anything else.

Comment: Can you `ping` the host?  If so, is the relevant port open on the remote system?

Comment: What is the output of `telnet 174.25.47.229 22`?

Comment: also, the output of >> nmap 174.25.47.229

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't an SSH key problem.  The time-out indicates that your machine
cannot even connect to the SSH server on the remote machine.

You might still have a key problem, but you won't find that out until
your SSH client actually connects with the remote SSH server.

You need to diagnose why your machine cannot connect to the SSH server
on port 22 (the default SSH port) on the remote machine:

- Perhaps the IP address you are using is wrong.  Try using `ping`
  on the address.  Maybe use `netcat` or `telnet` to try to connect with
  other ports on the same address (e.g. HTTP port 80) and make sure the
  machine actually exists:

  ```
  $ ping 174.25.47.229
  $ nc -v 174.25.47.229 80        # Try other well-known ports too
  $ telnet 174.25.47.229 80       # Use telnet if netcat not available
  ```
- Perhaps the SSH server runs on an non-standard port.  Find out.
- Perhaps the SSH server isn't even running at all on that machine.
  Find out.
- Perhaps a firewall blocks your access to that port only on that machine.
  Find out.
- Perhaps a firewall blocks your access to that port on *any* machine.
  Try other servers to see if they work.

Comment: hmmm thanks for so many options firewall was blocking port 22